# Save values into a list and send it to a function

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So I am trying to create a script where I loop through a text file where I want to be able to save all values from txt file and then send it into a function. I will explain it after the code below:

```
randomnames.txt

Alejandro  
Tisha  
Eleni  
Milton  
Jeanice  
Billye  
Vicki  
Shelba  
Valorie  
Penelope  
Mellissa  
Ambrose  
Retta  
Milissa  
Charline  
Brittny  
Ehtel  
Hilton  
Hobert  
Lakendra  
Silva  
Lawana  
Sidney  
Janeen  
Audrea  
Orpha  
Peggy  
Kay  
Marvis  
Tia  
Randy  
Cary  
Santana  
Roma  
Mandi  
Tyrone  
Felix  
Maybelle  
Leonia  
Micha  
Idalia  
Aleida  
Elfrieda  
Velia  
Cassondra  
Drucilla  
Oren  
Kristina  
Madison  
Dia  


names.txt

Alejandro
Tisha
Eleni
Dia
Hobert
```

---

```
import json, time, sys, os, timeit, random, colorama, requests, traceback, multiprocessing, re
from random import choice
import threading


def get_names():

    name_test = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('randomnames.txt')]
    return name_test

def filter(thread, i):

    text = thread

    positive_keywords = [i]

    has_good = False

    for ch in ['&', '#', '“', '”', '"', '*', '`', '*', '’', '-']:
        if ch in text:
            text = text.replace(ch, "")

    sentences = [text]

    def check_all(sentence, ws):
        return all(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(w), sentence) for w in ws)

    for sentence in sentences:
        if any(check_all(sentence, word.split('+')) for word in positive_keywords):
            has_good = True
            break

    if not has_good or i == "":
        sys.exit()

    print('Matched ' + text)

def main():
    old_list = []

    old_names_list = []

    while True:

        new_names_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('names.txt')]
        for new_thread in get_names():

            if not new_names_list == old_names_list:
                for i in new_names_list:
                    if not i in old_names_list:
                        threading.Thread(target=filter, args=(new_thread, i)).start()
                        if new_thread not in old_list:
                            old_list.append(new_thread)

            elif new_thread not in old_list:
                threading.Thread(target=filter, args=(new_thread, new_names_list)).start()
                old_list.append(new_thread)

        else:
            randomtime = random.randint(1, 3)
            print('No changes!')
            time.sleep(randomtime)

        old_names_list = new_names_list
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Keyboard - Interrupted' )
        sys.exit()
```

How the program works right now is that it checks all names in randomnames.txt and checks if any of these names matches names in names.txt. If there is a match it will print out there is a match, if not then it will just do sys.exit (Which kills the thread).

However my problem sits in the part of

```
if not new_names_list == old_names_list:
                    for i in new_names_list:
                        if not i in old_names_list:
                            threading.Thread(target=filter, args=(new_thread, i)).start()
                            if new_thread not in old_list:
                                old_list.append(new_thread)

                elif new_thread not in old_list:
                    threading.Thread(target=filter, args=(new_thread, new_names_list)).start()
                    old_list.append(new_thread)
```

Where I believe the problem is where it runs alot of threads due it takes one name from names.txt and checks all names one by one (thread) names in randomnames.txt. Meaning if there is 50 names in the randomnames.txt it will create 50 threads where it checks if any of names from randomnames.txt matches the name from names.txt. If it matches then it will print out there is a match. The problem is it needed to create 50 threads of just one name and meaning it will add another 50 threads for following new name.

The reason I believe that is a problem and how it can be solved is that if maybe adding all names from names.txt into a list and then send it to filter() where it checks if any in names.txt matches the names from randomnames.txt

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  What you posted, at best defines two functions and quits without calling either one of them: there's no main program, no output, etc.  I believe it fails for undefined packages.

Comment: Oh alright, then I might need to re-create a new thread whenever that is ready in that case ) Thanks @Prune. Also I am sorry.

Comment: Also, why are you forking off a new thread instead of simply iterating through the names in a single thread?

Comment: Wouldn't that take longer time due to its just gonna run one by one instead of giving it a thread? @Prune

Comment: Not at all -- the overhead of launching a new thread is *huge* in comparison to simple iteration.

Comment: hmm, i think the problem sits in that threading. Instead of sending a simple iteration to check each name, maybe it is better to add it to a list? @Prune

Comment: I expect so, but I'm going to wait for the MCVE before making any detailed comments.

Comment: @Prune I have just updated it. Feel free to check it out now. I hope it is better :) Should be able to run the script by copy pasting it and adding those txt files aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in orig post is grossly over-complicated.  Fundamentally, you are comparing two collections of names for matches.  This is set theory and you should be using Python sets to do this, not lists.  Consider:

```
names = {'Bob', 'Cindy', 'Dave'}
other_names = {'Lou', 'Pete', 'Cindy'}
print(names & other_names)  # {‘Cindy’}
```

Comment: I also believe that I have over-complicated everything. Do you might or have maybe time to give me tip to what I should do instead or can provide maybe an example on how I sohuld do the coding instead?